# Search option in XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

In Xcode,when we search for something by typing in the search field,the search operation is performed in the entire project.

Is it possible to select a particular portion of a class file and perform SEARCH only in that selected portion of code ?

Comment: yes... tap on the "in project" button and narrow the affected files.

Comment: CMD+"F" - search in the current file; SHIFT+CMD+"F" - search in entire project